# how to sync my database with drupal cms database periodically

Tags: database, drupal, content-management-system, backup

Hi I am new to Drupal7 cms so my question might be stupid but want to clarify here. My requirement is i have to develop a web application which uses 
 the database of drupal cms by making replica of the drupal cms database periodically(every halfanahour).So by making the copy of drupal cms database
 i want write my own web application as well as i want to create some webservices for the  mobile applcation ,by using this database.is it possible to
 do this if possible please let me know the steps of it. or tell me if there is any tools available for the auto syncing of my database with 
 drupal cms database . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [database replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html) in a master/slave setup if you have separate database servers. This way your database is constantly updated and you can write your web app to run off the slave never having to worry about the validity of the database data. If your databases are hosted on the same server you could use something as simple as [drush sql-sync](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-5x/sql/sql-sync).